# mp3 audio diration in python

Tags: python-3.x, macos, mp3, apple-m1

I need determine mp3 audio duration in python. I've tested:

- mutagen -- not very precise (+- 2 seconds)
- pymad -- it is worked well, but broken on my M1 Mac (return -1 on any request). maybe it is mad library broken -- I can't test it on my M1 Mac.

Do you know any other way to precisely get mp3 audio duration in python?

Thank you,
Andrii.

Answer (score 0):

pesox works great!
Precision is pretty good

```py
import sox
length = sox.file_info.duration(filename)
```